# cannot use threadprivate variable in gcc, clang works

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, openmp, eigen

I'm trying to optimise the following parallel execution to use threadprivate variables as the Eigen Vector evalInput could easily be thread_local and shared between iterations/tasks within a thread:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int j = 0; j < input.rows(); ++j)
{
    Eigen::VectorXf evalInput = input;
    // Modify one entry of evalInput, then restore after evaluating
    output.col(j) = factors * evalInput;
}
```

I tried to get evalInput to be shared per-thread with threadprivate and copyin, but even the most basic example does not work for me:

```cpp
static Eigen::VectorXf evalInput = input;
#pragma omp threadprivate(evalInput)

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) copyin(evalInput)
for (int j = 0; j < input.rows(); ++j)
{
    evalInput[j] += 1.0;
    output.col(j) = factors * evalInput;
    evalInput[j] = input[j];
}
```

Depending on the circumstances, I get the error `error: ‘threadprivate’ ‘evalInput’ has incomplete type` or `error: ‘evalInput’ declared ‘threadprivate’ after first use` (gcc 13.2.1).

However, notably, it does work in clang.

I prepared four simplified test cases, each changing one thing to the last, and not using Eigen, but simple vectors (so ignore that there is no point in using threadprivate here):

- `parallelBasic` being the basic implementation to optimise (as an example, not what I actually want to optimise) using templated Scalar.
- `parallelOpt` adds the threadprivate variable, yielding the incomplete type error.
- `parallelOptFloat` then drops the Scalar template, yielding in the first use error.
- `parallelVar` finally adds a random, unused templated parameter, and for some reason DOES compile.

It can be compiled with `g++ -o main -c main.cpp -Iinclude -fopenmp -lgomp` and it will fail, but when compiled with clang++ it does work:

```cpp
#include <omp.h>

#include <vector>

template<typename Scalar>
void parallelBasic(const std::vector<Scalar> &input, const std::vector<Scalar> &factors, std::vector<Scalar> &output)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); ++j)
    {
        output[j] = factors[j] * input[j];
    }
}

template<typename Scalar>
void parallelOpt(const std::vector<Scalar> &input, const std::vector<Scalar> &factors, std::vector<Scalar> &output)
{ // Does not work, "‘threadprivate’ ‘evalInput’ has incomplete type"
    static std::vector<Scalar> evalInput;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(evalInput)
    evalInput = input;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) copyin(evalInput)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); ++j)
    {
        output[j] = factors[j] * evalInput[j];
    }
}

void parallelOptFloat(const std::vector<float> &input, const std::vector<float> &factors, std::vector<float> &output)
{ // Removed templated Scalar, also does not work, "‘evalInput’ declared ‘threadprivate’ after first use"
    static std::vector<float> evalInput;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(evalInput)
    evalInput = input;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) copyin(evalInput)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); ++j)
    {
        output[j] = factors[j] * evalInput[j];
    }
}

template<typename Scalar>
void parallelVar(const std::vector<float> &input, const std::vector<float> &factors, std::vector<float> &output, Scalar value)
{ // Works, just added unused parameter
    static std::vector<float> evalInput;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(evalInput)
    evalInput = input;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) copyin(evalInput)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); ++j)
    {
        output[j] = factors[j] * evalInput[j];
    }
}

int main ()
{
    omp_set_dynamic(0);

    std::vector<float> input(100), factors(100), output(100);

    parallelBasic<float>(input, factors, output);

    //parallelOpt<float>(input, factors, output);

    //parallelOptFloat(input, factors, output);

    parallelVar(input, factors, output, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Post a [mcve] with all set #include.

Comment: will do, already noticing it is not that trivial (first attempt does compile fine)

Comment: Maybe slightly less optimal (but should be fine with cache), would `std::shared_ptr< Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,1>>`  work for you too?

Comment: @273K Added a compileable example with 4 test cases, and it revealed a lot more that I don't understand. Feel free to test it out.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Not sure how that would help, since I don't want a shared variable (threads are writing to it), but I also don't want a private variable (more allocations+copying than needed). The problem remaining with a thread_local variable (or a shared_ptr for that matter) would be that I need to initialise it with the input value, but I cannot rely on it being empty/invalid when I need to copy to it, since the thread might have been re-used from a previous run (with similar input), so for all intents and purposes it might look the same (save for comparing all values individually)

Comment: @Seneral: you say that threads are writing to the array, but the code does not support that statement, and, indeed, the `parallelBasic` version does not make a copy. So, if this is really what you're doing just use the simple version with a default schedule and all should be fine.

Comment: @JimCownie Yeah it's a bit of an issue when minimal reproducible example conflicts with what I really need. What I need is explained in the first snippet, a simple example (not real use ofc) in the second snippet which also shows how I wish to optimise it, and the test cases throw all that away and distill it down to the errors I face. If I can understand how to make the test cases work, I should be able to apply it to my use case where I actually need it. Seems like XY problem, but my full reasoning should still be there. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Interesting. Just tried clang, get "error: variable with local storage in initial value of threadprivate variable: `static std::vector<float> evalInput = input;` but not for parallelOpt, only parallelOptFloat and parallelVar, only difference I see is that it doesn't complain about the tempalted type. Wtf?
But good news, after I separated the assignment into a new line, it compiles, but gcc still doesn't

Comment: False alert, that function was still commented out with the other one, but as a template, was not compiled. And can confirm all work and give the same output on clang. Still not compiling with gcc/g++